# VLFeat compile for Octave: broken makefile

Tags: compilation, makefile, octave, archlinux, vlfeat

I'm attempting to complie VLFeat for use with Octave but the *.d files all end up in the VLFeat root directory. Which then causes the following error to appear for most of the files.

```
mv: cannot stat ‘./toolbox/geometry/vl_irodr.d’: No such file or directory
  MKOCTFILE toolbox/mex/octave/mexa64/vl_rodr.d
```

I instead of executing `MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile make` I defined `MKOCTFILE` in the octave.mak file as /bin/usr/mkoctfile and did not define the variable `MEX`.

I'm using version 0.9.19 of VLFeat, could anyone please tell me if my approach is wrong or how I can fix this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Have you tried doing the things you said you aren't doing (with the implication that those are the normal process)? Did that also fail?

Comment: Yes I did, I got the same error, when I execute using `MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile make`. And If I leave `MEX = mex` specified it recognises pdftex mex executable as a Matlab executable which causes even more errors.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone that is trying to compile VLFeat for Octave. 
Executing `make MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile` instead `MKOCTFILE=mkoctfile make` successfully compiled it for me. But VLFeat doesn't seem to support Octave properly still, most functions were complaining about missing functions they depend on.

I therefore decided to switch to Matlab which worked immediately.